# replace successive space, tab, newline characterset

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I have a NSString with successive space, tab, newlines. Is there any method to replay them by only one space? I have a small UIlabel view to display them.

Comment: give an example of your string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
NSString *string = @" spaces in front and at the end ";
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

The key here is whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet, from the Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nscharacterset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet):

```
Returns a character set containing only the whitespace characters space (U+0020) and tab (U+0009) and the newline and nextline characters (U+000A–U+000D, U+0085).
```

Comment: Yes, i do know this method. But i wanna to trim the whitespace in the middle of our string just like "spaces in the       middle"